# StreamWriter Error, Writing each character on a seperate line

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I currently have a list box, displaying blog items from "Blogs.txt"
Underneath is a textbox "currentPostTextBox"
I want to be able to write from the "currentPostTextBox" to the bottom of "Blogs.txt" but when it writes to the bottom of the file it ends up having each character on a seperate line..

```
using (StreamWriter postStreamWriter = 
     new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blogs.txt", true))
{
   foreach (var item in currentPostTextBox.Text)
   {
      postStreamWriter.WriteLine(item.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: `currentPostTextBox.Text` is a string, so you're iterating over every *character* in it with your `foreach` loop. What did you expect your `foreach` loop to iterate over?

Comment: You are writing every character on separate line... Not sure what exactly your question is (maybe "what return type of `TextBox.Text` is?" or "Why iterating over `string` produces characters?"). Side note: there is no need for "thank you notes" and "I'm new here"/"I'm new to XXXXX language" in your posts.

Comment: Been solved now thanks, needed to change postStreamWriter.WriteLine to postStreamWriter.Write. Thanks! (Seems silly I missed that)

Comment: @AshleyKrynen: But why not just use `postStreamWriter.Write(currentPostTextBox.Text)` in the first place? Why do you want to iterate character by character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashley, you are using the `writeline()` function, that's why it is writing in separate lines.

you should use `write()` function and you may need to add space or commas then, Depending on your scenario.

read about write() here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx

and WriteLine here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx

```
using (StreamWriter postStreamWriter = 
     new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blogs.txt", true))
{
   foreach (var item in currentPostTextBox.Text)
   {
      postStreamWriter.Write(item.ToString());
   }
}
```

**EDIT**  If you are willing to change the code, I have got this from a comment

`File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blogs.txt", currentPostTextBox.Text)`

Comment: That seems a very long-winded way of writing `File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blogs.txt", currentPostTextBox.Text)`